# Wikipedia Infobox Parser

Tags: c#, regex, wiki

I am converting the [wiki-infobox-parser](https://github.com/zp-j/wiki-infobox-parser/blob/master/lib/parser.js) to c#, but i am stuck on the regex to c#, i am not getting the same results in c# as i do in JS.

these are the ones.

```
var lists = text.match(/\{\{(order|bulleted|unbulleted|Pagelist)(.*\n)*?\}\}/g);
```

I tried this

```
var matches = text.Matches(@"(\{{(plainlist|order|bulleted|unbulleted|Pagelist)(?:\{??[^\{]*?\}}))");
```

but it doesnt seem to include all matches.

**Edit:**
Using a custom extension:

```
private static MatchCollection Matches(this string self, string expr)
{
   return Regex.Matches(self, expr, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: Why not use `var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"{{(order|bulleted|unbulleted|Pagelist)(.*\n)*?}}")`? It seems the `(.*\n)*?` should actually be turned into `(?s:.*?)`

Answer (score 0):

In your C# code, `text` seems to be a string that has no `Matches` method. You need to use [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches(v=vs.110).aspx) and actually the same regex will work:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"{{(order|bulleted|unbulleted|Pagelist)(.*\n)*?}}")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToList();
```

If you do not need the captured values in the 2 groups, either use non-capturing groups (`(?:...)`) or use the [`RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Explicit).